# Pidgin purple-facebook based account opens up many chatboxes automatically

Tags: pidgin, facebook, instant-messaging, libpurple

I installed the pidgin `purple-facebook` plugin. Whenever I create an account using this plugin, after pidgin logs into the facebook account, automatically my last 50 or so facebook chats open up in the chat-boxes. This freezes pidgin up for a while. This seems like a bug. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and plugin version is `purple-facebook_20150915~4f84a8a`. How can I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had over 150 unread messages in my inbox and pidgin was trying to open them all. A simple solution was to go to Accounts -> Manage Accounts -> Modify(the facebook account), go to the Advanced tab and untick 'Show unread messages'. This solved the issue. This never was a bug.